# Matching similar terms in ANTLR without capturing difference

Tags: antlr, antlr4, nand2tetris

As part of the [nand2tetris](http://www.nand2tetris.org/) challenge I'm trying to write a parser using ANTLR to generate machine code, having already implemented it using regex.

However, I'm struggling to work out how to use ANTLR effectively. A subset of the problem is below.

#### (Some) Valid instructions

```
 M=D
 D=M
 M=D+1
 D;JMP
 0;JMP
```

#### A (partial) Regex

```
(?<assignment>(?<destination>[ADM])=)?(?<computation>[ADM+10])(?<condition>;(?<jump>JMP))?
```

#### A (partial) grammar

```
command
     : assignment '=' computation
     | computation ';' condition
     | assignment '=' computation ';' condition
     ;

assignment
     : ASSIGNMENT
     ;

computation
     : OPERATION
     ;

condition
     : CONDITION
     ;

ASSIGNMENT
     : DESTINATION
     ;

CONDITION
     : JUMP
     ;

DESTINATION
     : 'A'
     | 'D'
     | ...etc
     ;

OPERATION
     : 'A'
     | 'D'
     | 'A+D'
     | ... etc
     ;

JUMP
     : JMP
     | JLE
     | etc...
     ;
```

Now, as you can see, the lexer will get mixed up between what is an computation and what is an assignment, as both could be 'A'...

However, if I change the ASSIGNMENT to

```
ASSIGNMENT
  : DESTINATION '='
  ;
```

and command to

```
command
  : assignment computation
  | etc...
```

then assignment picks up the equals sign.

So, I am trying to match under two tokens (FOO and FOO=) in different contexts, but I'm not interested in the =, only the FOO.

Am I barking up the wrong tree entirely with the current approach?

Comment: have the lexer tokenize 'A' as 1 specific token type and let your parser to decide what token type to accept at what context. Most of the time, only parser got the context information

Comment: Yep, barking up the wrong tree - totally had the concept wrong in my head. Seem to have it working now - thanks!